# Can you pause a form submission and then restart

Tags: javascript, forms, dom-events

Without using any JS libraries, is it possible to pause a form submission, run some code and then restart it?

Reason I ask is that I currently have a form that when it submits runs code that sends a request to my analytics provider. Works fine in Chrome/IE but in Firefox and Safari there is a drop out of these analytics of 60%.

The feeling is that the submission follows through before the scripts execute, hence why we are trying to pause the submit event.

Interested to hear any thoughts or insight.

Comment: A submit either fully succeeds or totally fails. It's a POST to the web server, if it doesn't arrive completely, the server (as for Apache and IIS at least) won't process it. Can you explain the problem a bit clearer?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `submit` event to cancel the form submission, do your analytics ajax stuff, and then submit the form programmatically using the `submit` method on the `form` element.

For example ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/uvoyoc)):

HTML:

```
<form id="theForm" action="#" method="GET">
  <label>Field: <input type="text" name="theField"></label>
  <br><input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var form, counter;

  form = document.getElementById("theForm");
  form.onsubmit = function() {
    if (typeof counter === "undefined") {
      display("Starting count down (" + counter + ")");
      counter = 3;
      setTimeout(delayedSubmit, 1000);
    }
    display("Cancelling form submit");
    return false;
  };

  function delayedSubmit() {
    if (typeof counter === "number") {
      --counter;
      if (counter > 0) {
        display("Continuing count down (" + counter + ")");
        setTimeout(delayedSubmit, 1000);
      }
      else {
        display("Count down complete, submitting form");
        counter = undefined;
        form.submit();
      }
    }
  }

  function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = msg;
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }
};
```

There I've used a count down timer rather than an ajax operation, but the principle is the same.

---

**Off-topic**: I've used the old DOM0 style of setting up an event handler there (`form.onsubmit = ...`). I don't recommend it, but it keeps the example simple. Setting up event handlers is one of the places where a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) can smooth over browser differences (and provide added functionality) for you, it's well worth considering using one.

Answer (score 2):

Just place a button in place of the submit button that runs the analytics script as a function, then submit the form with

```
document.forms["myform"].submit();
```

See this site [How to submit a form through javascript](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml).
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the `submit` event. Something like:

```
(function() {
    var processed = false;

    form.onsubmit = function(event) {
        event = event || window.event;
        if(!processed) {
            if(event.preventDefault) {      // cancel default action
                event.preventDefault();
            }
            else {
                event.returnValue = false;
            }

            // run your code
            // execute the next two lines in a callback if necessary
            processed = true;
            form.submit();
        }
    };
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the function to run on event `"onsubmit"`, return a false from the event handler if you want to cancel the form submission, or use below:

```
function onSubmitHandler(evnt){

//run some code set some flag
if(flag is set) evnt.preventDefault(); else return true;

}
```